# Oracle: create keystore

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

I am trying to create a keystore in oracle. Reading from the documentation found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17609/tdpsg_encryption.htm#TDPSG44323)

I verified the compatible string it is above 11.2.0.0. Now the next step I run the Administer key management command

```
SQL> administer key management create keystore ´/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/ORA_KEYSTORES´ identified by password;
administer key management create keystore ´/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/ORA_KEYSTORES´ identified by password
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-46604: invalid or missing keystore file name


SQL>
```

I am getting the above error. I made the entry in sqlnet.ora file. The contents of file is as below.

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

ENCRYPTION_WALLET_LOCATION=
 (SOURCE=
  (METHOD=file)
   (METHOD_DATA=
    (DIRECTORY=/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/ORA_KEYSTORES)))
```

How to resolve this problem.
Also I am not able to enter single quote in terminal.

```
OS: ubuntu 12.04
Oracle: 12c release enterprise edition
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to enter single quote in terminal"? Sounds like you know why it isn't working and have a much wider problem. Are you running Ubuntu in a VM and have the wrong keymap? If so does [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/155424) help? (I don't have that distro so can't experiment).

Comment: What I mean by saying ¨I am not able to enter single quotes in terminal¨ is when I press the single quote key it automatically displays the back tick in the terminal. I suppose the problem is because of this only. And I am not running ubuntu in VM.

Comment: You still should look at your keyboard mapping then. If this isn't specific to Oracle, and you know what is wrong with how your code is being created, then maybe you should ask about the general quote key issue on AskUbuntu - if you can't see any existing question that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using non standard quotes (`´`) to delimit your string, instead of straight quotes (`'`):

```
administer key management create keystore 
  '/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/ORA_KEYSTORES'
  identified by password;
```

Comment: I also believe that the problem is because of this reason only. But I am not able to enclose the string in single quote. When I press single quote key it displays backtick ´ Not just in terminal everywhere I press single quote key it displays backtick